# Spring4Shell detection without knowing spring, JDK version, or code

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

I understand that popular exploits for Sping4Shell are performed by submitting HTTP POST requests with form data that attempts to get server-side data-binding code to alter a classLoader field. How do I construct this request?

Comment: HTTP GET requests with forged headers are also possible.

Comment: @ValerijDobler , what sort of forged headers? I am a novice at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many GitHub projects, which maintain code for testing for those vulnerabilities. For example [this one](https://github.com/redhuntlabs/Hunt4Spring/blob/main/main.go).

Study the source code and rebuild it in a language you fancy. Or use it out of the box. There are also solutions, which run in Docker, so no additional resources are needed.